# AddressBook Listener

Tags: iphone

I am doing one application which should notify me changes (like update , delete, etc) in  contacts of addressbook ie `ABAddressBook` is used to get all the address contacts. I read that  `ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback` will give notifications, but I am not sure how it will work. I wanted to store changes even though my application is closed. Let me know anybody has worked upon same or any inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You will only get a callback when you run your application. It's not possible to get a notification when the application is not running.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS4+, if your app is in the background and a foreground app changes the address book, your callback will be called when your app is next brought to the foreground (i.e., not in "real time").  If your app is totally terminated then, of course, it behaves like pre-iOS4.